# Using queries containing pseudo-classes in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm tring to use pseudo classes in programmtic query using `Node.lookupAll()` however this seems to give unexpected results.

I've searched online and can't find anything to suggest Node.lookupAll() wouldn't support psuedo classes...

```
public class Foo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        PseudoClass pseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("custom");

        Label a = new Label();
        a.getStyleClass().add("foo");
        a.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, false);

        Label b = new Label();
        b.getStyleClass().add("foo");
        b.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, true);

        Label c = new Label();
        c.getStyleClass().add("foo");
        c.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, true);


        HBox box = new HBox(a, b, c);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));

        System.out.println(box.lookupAll(":custom").size()); // expected 2
        System.out.println(box.lookupAll(".foo:custom").size()); // expected 2
        System.out.println(box.lookupAll(".foo").size()); // expected 3, got 3
        System.out.println(box.lookupAll(":magichorse").size()); // expected 0 !!

    }

}
```

Output

```
4
3
3
4
```

Comment: What are the actual results you are getting? Or are they different every time?

Comment: (Note there's a copy-and-paste bug in the test code on the calls to `pseudoClassStateChanged(...)`, though it makes no difference.) It looks like it is completely ignoring the pseudoclass in the lookup. `:custom` and `:magichorse` give the `HBox` and the three labels (same as `lookup("*")`), `.foo:custom` and `.foo` give the three labels. That would seem to be a bug (at the very least in the documentation: if pseudoclasses are not supported in lookups it should be documented). A possible workaround is just to filter the lookup via `getPseudoClassStates().contains(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug, or at least undocumented feature. No one has said otherwise, and the JDK team have accepted my bug report.

See [JDK-8185831](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8185831)

As a workaround `getPseudoClassStates().contains(...)` can be used instead.