# JavaFX TextArea - Controlling the scroll bar sizes

Tags: javafx

Unpleasantly surprised by TextArea CSS font sizes having wacky effects on the sizes of the scroll bars, I'm trying to get control of the sizes myself. Please refer to the following SSCCE. I can easily control the vertical scroll bar, but the horizontal bar is simply ignoring the sizes I'm setting. Am I expecting something unreasonable here, or is this (yet another) bug in JavaFX? Thanks!

[image]

```
public class Main extends Application { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        int lineCount = 100;
        int wordCount = 70;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int lineNbr = 0; lineNbr < lineCount; lineNbr++) {
            for (int wordNbr = 0; wordNbr < wordCount; wordNbr++) {
                sb.append("Sample");
            }
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        textArea.setText(sb.toString());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(textArea);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        double prefSize = 50;
        ScrollBar vertScrollBar = (ScrollBar)textArea.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        ScrollBar horizScrollBar = (ScrollBar)textArea.lookup(".scroll-bar:horizontal");

        vertScrollBar.setPrefWidth(prefSize); // This works great!

        horizScrollBar.setPrefHeight(prefSize); // This doesn't do anything!
        horizScrollBar.setMinHeight(prefSize); // Nor does this
        horizScrollBar.setPrefWidth(prefSize); // Nor this
        horizScrollBar.setMinWidth(prefSize); // Nor this

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScrollBar vertScrollBar = (ScrollBar) textArea.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
ScrollBar horizScrollBar = (ScrollBar) textArea.lookup(".scroll-bar:horizontal");
System.out.println(vertScrollBar + " " + horizScrollBar);
```

> ScrollBar@35ef2d94[styleClass=scroll-bar]
>   ScrollBar@35ef2d94[styleClass=scroll-bar]

Same object (vertical ScrollBar).

```
    ScrollPane sPane = (ScrollPane)textArea.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
    ScrollBar horizScrollBar = (ScrollBar)sPane.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(2);
    horizScrollBar.setPrefHeight(prefSize); // This does something!
```

[image]

**Update**: Better way to receive the two ScrollBars.

```
ScrollBar[] bars = new ScrollBar[2];
textArea.lookupAll(".scroll-bar").toArray(bars);
bars[0].setPrefWidth(prefSize);
bars[1].setPrefHeight(prefSize);
```

**Edit**: Explanation for similar problem with lookupAll(...) and pseudo classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207442/using-queries-containing-pseudo-classes-in-javafx) and [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8185831).

Comment: That works, thanks! I can't understand why Oracle is making such a mess with JavaFX. How hard can it be to give more direct access to things like this (as well as not pollute a stand-alone windowing toolkit with CSS trash as the only way to change Text control colors and fonts, but I digress).

Comment: @BinaryDigit09 In swing, too much access was given to things that should have been kept as internal implementation; because of that pretty much any time they tried to add or change things, they broke existing client code. JavaFX, rightly or wrongly (and I think rightly; I'd rather not have access to stuff than get screwed over each time a customer upgrades their JVM, YMMV of course) takes a more conservative approach and keeps the implementation hidden. Lookups provide a way to hack into that in many cases, but at that point you are operating outside of spec (i.e. buyer beware).

Comment: @James_D I've been making Swing apps professionally since 1.4 and I've never affected my customers' Java upgrade path by having direct control over basic attributes of my GUI components such as sizes and colors, nor by overriding certain functions in the Swing JDK (the equivalents of which are liberally and IMO arrogantly flagged as final in JFX). Don't get me wrong, my argument is not with you personally. But if that's Oracle's reason for not providing better control over GUI components than hacky string-literal map lookups, that's ridiculous! Sorry, rough day, mostly due to Java FX. Cheers!

Comment: @BinaryDigit09 But as my answer points out, you don't need to use a lookup for any of this, unless you're trying to avoid using the toolkit the way it's intended to be used. You *do* have direct control over these things in FX: via CSS *or* API calls for the controls themselves (see, e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setTextFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setFont-javafx.scene.text.Font-) for the "examples" you cite above) , and CSS for their internals.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the references, but unfortunately TextField and TextArea both extend TextInputControl, not Labeled, so they have setFont but not setTextFill I'm afraid. Nor are there any API functions such as setBackgroundColor, setBorderColor, setFocusedBorderColor, setTextBackground, setTextForeground, setSelectedTextBackground, setSelectedTextForeground. I've implemented all of these for myself in custom sublasses for ease of use and they do the dirty CSS setStyle stuff for me. But then JavaFX mis-handles the scroll bars and I get to figure out how to un-break it. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @BinaryDigit09 Ah, ok, didn't realize you were referring to text input controls. Again, the actual recommendation from the toolkit is to style the application with an external style sheet. I think if you try that, rather than inline styles and lookups, you'll find it works better. I have several apps in FX and I don't have a single lookup (any more). (I have also got out of the old swing habit of subclassing everything in sight.) Anyway... this is probably not the right place for this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Lookups are generally pretty fragile (and I don't think they're really intended to be robust); as noted in the links from the other answer they don't appear to support pseudoclasses.

You can of course just use CSS for this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        int lineCount = 100;
        int wordCount = 70;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int lineNbr = 0; lineNbr < lineCount; lineNbr++) {
            for (int wordNbr = 0; wordNbr < wordCount; wordNbr++) {
                sb.append("Sample");
            }
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        textArea.setText(sb.toString());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250) ;

        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

with the following in `style.css`:

```css
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-pref-height: 50 ;
}
.scroll-pane .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-pref-width: 50 ;
}
```

[image]

This approach, of course, is far more convenient if you have multiple scroll panes in your application and want them all to have the same style of scroll bars.